# SKAction on a programmatically built node? How to target the node?

Tags: sprite-kit, skaction, sknode

I had previously used a separate method for each character and wrote them in each scene file but it was messy and huge.

So in an effort to clean up code I wrote a buildCharater method to create the characters I need in different scenes. As you can see it also builds the associated texture atlas and the animation action. However I need to have these characters build in a non active state - and when touched the animation begins along with other actions.  I am able to detect touches using an if let switch on the optional names but I cannot sort how to call an action on the individual nodes - previous to this I was able to do node.run(someAction) but now I'm lost on how to target the individual nodes as well as animate them with the associated atlas's. Here is the buildCharacter method -

```
func buildCharacter(name:String, height: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, position: CGPoint, zPosition: CGFloat) {
    let animatedAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: name)
    var animationFrames: [SKTexture] = []
    
    let numImages = animatedAtlas.textureNames.count
    for i in 1...numImages {
        let textureName = "\(name)\(i)"
        
        animationFrames.append(animatedAtlas.textureNamed(textureName))
    }
    
    animatedCharacter = animationFrames
    let firstFrameTexture = animatedCharacter[0]
    builtCharacter = SKSpriteNode(texture: firstFrameTexture)
    builtCharacter.size.height = height
    builtCharacter.size.width = width
    builtCharacter.position = position
    builtCharacter.zPosition = zPosition
    builtCharacter.name = name
    
    isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    addChild(builtCharacter)
    builtCharacters.append(builtCharacter)
    
    let animationAction = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: animatedCharacter, timePerFrame: 0.1, resize: false, restore: true))
    builtCharacter.run(animationAction)
    
   }
```

I do not want to run the action immediately like it currently does - I want to be able to start and stop the action(s) via touches began.

I had previously written an animation method for each character but am trying to streamline the whole thing - open to any ideas!

Thanks

Comment: I would create the variable `animationAction` outside the scope of the function, say at the top of the class, then change `let animationAction` to `animationAction`, as well as remove `builtCharacter.run(animationAction)`. When the `buildCharacter` function gets run, this variable will have the animation stored and ready to be used. Then when a touch is detected use `builtCharacter.run(animationAction)`

Comment: Oh that is a good idea - but only addresses part of the situation. I have 5 characters - they each come out of the method as builtCharacter - I need to be able to run actions on them individually as well as various groupings of nodes based on which node was touched. So lets say I have character1 and character2 - when I touch character1 I want to run actions on character1 and character2 - so calling builtCharacter.run(someAnimation) doesn't quite work - does that make sense? How do I target specific nodes if they all come out of the method as builtCharacter?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can get the nodes at your touch location using this code in `touchesBegan`:

```
  for t in touches {
    
    let location = t.location(in: self)
    let touchedNodes = self.nodes(at: location)
    
    for node in touchedNodes {
      let sprite = node as! SKSpriteNode
      sprite.run(animationAction)
    }
  }
```

This will run the animation on whatever nodes are found at your touch location. `touchedNodes` is an array which stores all nodes found at your location. They are stored as `SKNode` so you can convert them to `SKSpriteNode` if need be.

You can add an `if` statement in the `for node..` which checks the `node.name`, and you can then run specific animations depending on what node you have selected. In your example in your comment, if you clicked on character1 and want to run animations on character1 AND character2, you could use:

```
for node in touchedNodes {
    if node.name == "character1" {
      let char1 = node as! SKSpriteNode
      char1.run(animationAction)
      let char2 = childNode(withName: "//character2") as? SKSpriteNode
      char2.run(animationAction)
    } //else if node.name ==....


}
```

Comment: I have been playing with this approach and the issue is that animationAction variable only stores the action/atlas of the last builtCharacter. So if run buildCharacter 5 times for 5 different characters in viewDidLoad - the only stored action is the last built character - I wonder if I can load each action/atlas into an array and access them as needed? I have 4 scenes with 5 characters (all the same) so the whole idea is just to reduce repeated code - I can make this work very easily - but really want to try an approach like this...

Comment: I see what you are saying. You could store all your animations in a dictionary maybe, and give them a recognisable key. Build all of this in a function called from didMoveTo view. You can then pull out whichever animation you need as and when.